# How to keep the border after the checkbox is active/selected in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So what I have right now is
[image: this], borderless check box when checked

What I want to achieve is [image: this], a bordered checkbox when checked

This is my code for the checkbox i have:

```
Checkbox(
          value: _isChecked,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              _isChecked = value;
            });
           },
          checkColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
          activeColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
Text("Remember me")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can wrap it in a container and set a border for it
[How to add a border to a widget in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423297/how-to-add-a-border-to-a-widget-in-flutter%5C)
then you can use theme(unselectedwidgetcolor:)to change the default border  of checkbox 
[change checkbox border-color in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651366/how-to-change-checkbox-border-color-in-flutter-by-default-it-is-showing-black%5C)
then according these question we can use both ,to achieve what we want

```
bool _isChecked = false;
```

then we can define our check box and say if isChecked was equal by true ,color would be pink accent if not change it to white by a `ternary if`

```
  Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                  color: _isChecked == true ? Colors.pinkAccent: Colors.black,
                  width: 2.3),
            ),
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            child: Theme(
              data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white),
              child: Checkbox(
                checkColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                activeColor: Colors.transparent,
                value: _isChecked,
                tristate: false,
                onChanged: (bool isChecked) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isChecked = isChecked;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

with code above you would get something like this
[image]

you can also change the pink border to whatever you want

Answer (score 6):

```
side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                              (states) => BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    width: 1.5,
                                  )),
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: This answer was already given. What is new?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this using `Theme`, you can override it like this:

```dart
runApp(MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
      checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((_) => Colors.black),
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((_) => Colors.transparent),
      side: AlwaysActiveBorderSide(),
    ),
  ),
));

class AlwaysActiveBorderSide extends MaterialStateBorderSide {
  @override
  BorderSide? resolve(_) => const BorderSide(color: Colors.black54);
}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 5):

Using **MaterialStateBorderSide** you can achieve the expected view

```
bool state = false;


 Checkbox(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              ),
              activeColor: Colors.pink,
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                (states) => const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              value: state,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  state = value!;
                });
              },
            ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Checkbox` border is controlled by its `side` property. The docs list a small gotcha though: `side` must use a `MaterialStateBorderSide` to control the appearance of a checked `Checkbox` otherwise `side` only controls **unchecked** checkboxes (for backwards compatibility)

We should also style all of our `Checkbox` widgets using a `Theme` for the sake of consistency and efficiency, so we end up with:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
      checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.pinkAccent),

      // For every Material state we return the same border style
      side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith((states) => BorderSide(
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
          )),
    ),
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Checkbox(
        value: _isChecked,
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            _isChecked = value;
          });
        },
      ),
      Text("Remember me"),
    ],
  ),
);
```